# Create PDF where each page is a merge of image and a SVG file

Tags: pdf, svg, automation, imagemagick, pdftk

I have a sequence of images 1.jpg, 2.jpg, ... , 10.jpg and a sequence of SVGs 1.svg, 2.svg, ... , 10.svg. Is it possible to transform them into a single PDF document, where the i'th page is a composition of i.svg on top of i.jpg? Namely, I would like to position i.svg over i.jpg - as the i'th page in the document.

I know pdfTk can sometimes be helpful for such tasks, but I couldn't figure a way to achieve this. I also tried ImageMagick, using the following command:

```
composite -compose atop -geometry "20%+10%" -gravity southwest "1.svg" "2.jpg" "output.pdf"
```

but the output was distorted.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do that in Imagemagick using -layers composite as follows

```
convert -density XX *.svg null: *.jpg -compose atop -layers composite result.pdf
```

You can replace *.svg with a list of svg file and *.jpg with a list of jpg files. The wild card * will get them all in the current directory in alphabetic order. The null: separator is important for -layers composite.  Set the SVG desired density to control the size of the rasterized SVG file.

You may add -geometry before -compose atop, but it does not work in percent. You will need to compute that as pixels. If you need each image offset the same percentage, then you will need to use Imagemagick 7, so that you can do

```
magick -density XX *.svg null: *.jpg -geometry "+%[fx:20*w/100]+%[fx:10*h/100]" -compose atop -layers composite result.pdf
```

Unfortunately, Imagemagick 6 does not support that capability.

Comment: It prints errors for each svg file:
"negative or zero image size"
"no decode delegate for this image format"

Comment: What was your exact command line?  What version of Imagemagick and platform?  zero size probably means the file is empty or bad or the wrong path.

Comment: I probably used the wrong path, because now it finds the files (using the first command you offered). However, I get a blank PDF instead of what I wanted. The following errors are printed during the operation:
"unknown line cap style"
"CSS parsing error"
"couldn't load font X, falling back to Y"

Comment: I could use inkscape to batch convert each SVG file to a PDF file. The conversion is accurate. In that case, can I use magick to place a specific background image to every pdf?

Comment: Yes, but if save as PDF, then the result will not be vector, but a raster image imbedded in a vector shell.

Comment: @Ido have you managed to get it running? I'm struggling with exactly the same issue: how to create PDF from jpgs and svgs on top of them

Comment: Unfortunately no :/